# Force Close App when display data into listview using asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

when i run applicatiom was force close. this application function is display data from sqlite in listview by using asynctask. but i get error in nullpointer at

> collegeList.add(map); --> nullpointer

Then, i want is, data will display by id. the id is foreign key.

this my code:

```
private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> collegeList;
    protected void onPreExecute()
    { super.onPreExecute();}

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        List<Rainday> raindaydetail = new LinkedList<Rainday>();
        raindaydetail=dbHelper.getAllRainday();

        for(Rainday temp_vg: raindaydetail){
            temp_vg.getId();
            temp_vg.getYear_rainday();
            temp_vg.getJan();
            temp_vg.getFeb();
            temp_vg.getMar();
            temp_vg.getApr();
            temp_vg.getMay();
            temp_vg.getJun();
            temp_vg.getJul();
            temp_vg.getAug();
            temp_vg.getSep();
            temp_vg.getOct();
            temp_vg.getNov();
            temp_vg.getDec();

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put("id", String.valueOf(temp_vg.getId()));
            map.put("year_rainfall", temp_vg.getYear_rainday());
            map.put("jan", temp_vg.getJan());
            map.put("feb", temp_vg.getFeb());
            map.put("mar", temp_vg.getMar());
            map.put("apr", temp_vg.getApr());
            map.put("may", temp_vg.getMay());
            map.put("jun", temp_vg.getJun());
            map.put("jul", temp_vg.getJul());
            map.put("aug", temp_vg.getAug());
            map.put("sep", temp_vg.getSep());
            map.put("oct", temp_vg.getOct());
            map.put("nov", temp_vg.getNov());
            map.put("dec", temp_vg.getDec());

          collegeList.add(map);
    }

    return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

{
    proCollageList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    listCollege.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (collegeList != null) {
        ListAdapterRainday adapter = new ListAdapterRainday(RaindayReport.this, collegeList);
        listCollege.setAdapter(adapter);}}
```

MySQLiteHelper :

```
 public List<Rainday> getAllRainday() {
    List<Rainday> rainday = new LinkedList<Rainday>();
    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_RAINDAY + " WHERE id = " + KEY_ID_RAINDAY;
    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
    Rainday rainday1 = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            rainday1 = new Rainday();
            rainday1.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            rainday1.setYear_rainday(cursor.getString(1));
            rainday1.setJan(cursor.getString(2));
            rainday1.setFeb(cursor.getString(3));
            rainday1.setMar(cursor.getString(4));
            rainday1.setApr(cursor.getString(5));
            rainday1.setMay(cursor.getString(6));
            rainday1.setJun(cursor.getString(7));
            rainday1.setJul(cursor.getString(8));
            rainday1.setAug(cursor.getString(9));
            rainday1.setSep(cursor.getString(10));
            rainday1.setOct(cursor.getString(11));
            rainday1.setNov(cursor.getString(12));
            rainday1.setDec(cursor.getString(13));
            // Add vgm
            rainday.add(rainday1);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return rainday;
}
```

i need your help. if anybody helped me, i will appreciate it.

Comment: Its just a null pointer.. Look for why your list is null. Have you initialized it?

Answer (score 2):

i think you forgot to initialize your **collegeList**

just initialize it like this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> collegeList;
        collegeList= new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I found below line

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> collegeList;
```

And you are not initializing collegeList any where in your code